# sql turn dates of adding and removing into date ranges

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005, t-sql

I am using a timetabling application called CELCAT and trying to pull out some data about when students should have been marked for reporting... This seems to be extremely difficult because of the way the adding and removing of students on registers is structured see below:

```
studentid   eventid     fromdatetime                addition    removal
25149       25145       2009-09-12 10:30:00.000     Y           NULL
25149       25145       2009-09-12 10:30:00.000     NULL        Y
25149       25145       2009-09-12 10:30:00.000     Y           NULL
25150       23013       2009-09-08 09:00:00.000     Y           NULL
25150       23554       2009-09-07 09:00:00.000     Y           NULL
25150       25145       2009-09-12 10:30:00.000     Y           NULL
25150       25145       2009-07-27 00:00:00.000     NULL        Y
25150       25145       2009-09-12 10:30:00.000     Y           NULL
25150       25145       2009-09-12 10:30:00.000     NULL        Y
25150       25145       2009-09-12 10:30:00.000     Y           NULL
25150       25148       2009-09-12 15:00:00.000     Y           NULL
25151       25145       2009-09-12 10:30:00.000     Y           NULL
25151       25145       2009-10-10 00:00:00.000     NULL        Y
25152       25145       2009-09-19 10:30:00.000     Y           NULL
25152       25145       2009-07-27 00:00:00.000     NULL        Y
```

So an addition of a student means they should be marked from that date onwards in the register (registers are weekly reccurring events with their own week profile, I can handle that side of it though). A removal would mean the student doesn't need to be marked past this date, however a student could potentially be added, removed and then re-added in a later week.

What I think would get me in the right direction would be to get a table of structure

```
studentid    eventid    fromdate                      todate
25149          25145    2009-09-12 10:30:00.000       2009-09-28 10:30:00.000     
25149          25145    2009-10-13 10:30:00.000       2009-10-24 10:30:00.000
```

Any ideas how to do this? Or a better suggestion? I imagine it will involve some use of cursors unless someone has an awesome solution. The tables are designed by CELCAT and cannot be modified.

Oh yeah it's sql server 2005.

**EDIT** by KM, here is some code to test solutions with:

```
DECLARE @YourTable table (studentid int
                         ,eventid int
                         ,fromdatetime datetime
                         ,addition char(1) 
                         ,removal char(1)
                         )

SET NOCOUNT ON
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25149,25145,'2009-09-12 10:30:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25149,25145,'2009-09-12 10:30:00.000', NULL,'Y')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25149,25145,'2009-09-12 10:30:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25150,23013,'2009-09-08 09:00:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25150,23554,'2009-09-07 09:00:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25150,25145,'2009-09-12 10:30:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25150,25145,'2009-07-27 00:00:00.000', NULL,'Y')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25150,25145,'2009-09-12 10:30:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25150,25145,'2009-09-12 10:30:00.000', NULL,'Y')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25150,25145,'2009-09-12 10:30:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25150,25148,'2009-09-12 15:00:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25151,25145,'2009-09-12 10:30:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25151,25145,'2009-10-10 00:00:00.000', NULL,'Y')
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25152,25145,'2009-09-19 10:30:00.000','Y'  ,NULL)
INSERT INTO @YourTable VALUES (25152,25145,'2009-07-27 00:00:00.000', NULL,'Y')
SET NOCOUNT OFF
```

Comment: how do you get those two date range rows from the given sample data? it is hard to make a query for you when the "answer" you want does not match the given sample data.

Comment: Is there another column in this table/view which would indicate the timestamp when the record was added or at least incremental identifier? If not, then it is quite tough to have a logic for your student with ID=25149, because he is added and removed to/from the same event 3 times, but it is not clear what was done first.

Comment: it would also help if you indicated what "final" result would you like to have, and not just ".. right direction ..". thanks

Comment: how can you ask a question, yet provide ZERO feedback to those people trying to help?

Answer (score 0):

One simple way would be to create a scalar function which for a studentid and an eventid returned a bit indicating whether that student is in or out:

```
create function Event_IsStudentIn(@eventID int, @studentID int)
returns bit as
begin
    declare @in bit

    set @in = 0

    select 
     @in = case when addition = 'Y' then 1 else 0 end
    from [table]
    where eventid = @eventID and studentid = @studentID
    order by fromdatetime desc                  

    return @in
end
```

However in the future you may want to restructure that data.

Comment: I don't see how this solves, it perhaps I haven't phrased the question well enough.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure of the query you are trying to get and how date ranges will help.

However, you could keep the current table, it is like a log.  Just add a summary table that keeps the current state.  Insert the old table and UPDATE the new one.  you can query the new one to tell if IN/OUT and use the old one for more detailed analysis.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure what you need to be able to do with the data, but here's how to get the data into the format you wanted.

```
SELECT studentid, eventid, fromdatetime as fromdate, 
    (SELECT TOP 1 fromdatetime FROM table 
    WHERE studentid = t1.studentid 
        AND eventid = t1.eventid 
        AND removal = 'Y' AND fromdatetime > t1.fromdatetime
    ) AS todate
FROM table t1
WHERE addition = 'Y'
```

This query will produce the data in the format you asked for:

```
studentid    eventid   fromdate                      todate
25149        25145     2009-09-12 10:30:00.000       2009-09-28 10:30:00.000
25149        25145     2009-10-13 10:30:00.000       2009-10-24 10:30:00.000
```

This query will probably be inefficient with lots of data, so I'm really hoping your table has an identity row that's indexed.  If it does, replace the `AND fromdatetime > t1.fromdatetime` with `AND id > t1.id`.  This should make the subquery more efficient.

Comment: I tried this query and it does not work.  I'll edit the original question with a table definition and inserts to populate the sample data.  from there all you have to do is replace the two "FROM table" with "FROM @YourTable" and use the code I put in the original question.

Comment: I've looked at this, and the query does work exactly the way I thought it should, but the problem at the moment is the data.  Perhaps I have misunderstood the structure of the data, but in the sample data above, there are removals after inserts, multiple inserts on the same day, inserts and removals on the same day.

Perhaps the OP could explain exactly what the data represents, and whether the sample posted above is live data or a mockup.

Answer (score 0):

I think there's something wrong with the sample data
First 3 records

```
25149     25145    2009-09-12 10:30:00.000      Y          NULL
25149     25145    2009-09-12 10:30:00.000      NULL        Y
25149     25145    2009-09-12 10:30:00.000      Y           NULL
```

Basically they say, the student was added/removed and added again at the same time.
However, remember when selecting the order is not guaranteed. How does one know the student wasn't removed first and then added twice?
The question asks for the row

```
25149        25145     2009-10-13 10:30:00.000       2009-10-24 10:30:00.000
```

in the output, but the '2009-10-13' value is nowhere in the data.

Then these three:

```
25150     25145    2009-09-12 10:30:00.000        Y               NULL
25150     25145    2009-07-27 00:00:00.000      NULL            Y
25150     25145    2009-09-12 10:30:00.000      Y           NULL
```

Exactly the hypothetical scenario I described above - judging by the date, the student was removed first and then added twice!